# Homology groups of $n-1$-sphere and $n$-ball

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms), one can use the axiomatic definition of homology to compute the homology groups os simple spaces, such as that of the $n-1$-sphere $S^{n-1}$, and the $n$-ball $B^n$, which can then be used to show that $S^{n-1}$ is not a retract of $B^n$, which is useful to prove Brouwer's theorem.

However I don't see how to do so.

Using the first axiom, one gets that if $(X,A), (Y,B)$ are homotpy equivalent, then for all $k$ one should have $H_k(X,A)\simeq H_k(Y,B)$. Setting $A=B=\emptyset, X= B^n, Y= \{\star\}$, one gets $H_k(X) \simeq H_k(P)$, which for $k\neq 0$ yields (with the dimension axiom) that $H_k(X) \simeq 0$.

But from then on, I can't make any progress: I can't calculate $H_0(B^n)$ (even if it's not useful to show the properties I mentioned above, it would be interesting to know if I can), nor can I calculate $H_k(S^{n-1})$ (in particular I don't see how there is an axiom that would allow us to get to "$H_{n-1}(S^{n-1})$ isn't trivial").

So my question is : these groups be computed only with the axioms, and if so, how ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate from the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms that $H_0(B^n)$ is isomorphic to the coefficient group $H_0(P)$ (where $P$ is a point) and you can calculate $H_k(S^{n-1})$ in terms of $H_0(P)$. The coefficient group is effectively a parameter to the axioms. However, the axioms are compatible with the coefficient group being the trivial group $\{0\}$. To derive any useful topological conclusions from the axioms, you need to exhibit a homology theory for which the coefficient group is non-trivial. The Wikipedia page you cite has missed that point.

Comment: How can you calculate $H_k(S^{n-1})$ in terms of $H_0(P)$ ?

Comment: That's a standard argument by induction using the long exact sequence of the pairs $(B^n, S^{n-1})$.

Comment: I've shown that $\partial : H_{k+1}(B^n, S^{n-1}) \simeq H_k(S^{n-1})$ for each $k\geq 0$, but I don't see how that would help. I'm new to this kind of reasoning and I basically only know what's on the wikipedia page, could you perhaps elaborate on the standard argument used here ?

Comment: Let me suggest that this is an excellent place in your learning to learn not to depend on wikipedia. These arguments are contained in many, many excellent textbooks on Algebraic Topology.

Comment: Are you self-studying homology theory? If so, you will need a better source than Wikipedia to learn the basic techniques.

Comment: @RobArthan I'm not learning homology theory (yet), I just needed this calculation for a (short) presentation for an algebra class

Comment: @LeeMosher I'm sure they are, but I'm not currently studying algebraic topology, I'm just preparing a short presentation for an algebra class